# What is causing Vertex AI file download error?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

Vertex AI occasionally fails to download any file greater than 30M (any downloaded file will be trimmed at 30M). Download speed seems to be slower as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you download files from your user-managed notebooks instance, a timeout setting on the proxy-forwarding agent limits the connection time for the download to complete. If the download takes too long, this can truncate your downloaded file or prevent it from being downloaded.

To download the file, [copy your file to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#upload-object-cli), and then download the file from Cloud Storage.

Consider [migrating your files and data](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/migrate) to a new user-managed notebooks instance.